What does the address of a function item represent in rust-lldb?
I am using rust-lldb to explore function item & function pointer in Rust. The code is very simple:
// src/main.rs


#[inline(never)]
fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

#[inline(never)]
fn sub(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a - b
}

fn main() {
    let item = add; // function item
    let item1 = sub; // function item

    let ptr: fn(i32, i32) -> i32 = add; // function pointer
    let x = item(1, 2);
    let y = item1(3, 2);
    let z = ptr(1, 2);
    assert_eq!(3, x);
    assert_eq!(1, y);
    assert_eq!(3, z);
}

When I set a breakpoint and start debugging, I found that both item & item1 points to an invalid address
➜  function git:(master) ✗ rust-lldb --version
lldb-1500.0.404.7
Apple Swift version 5.10 (swiftlang-5.10.0.13 clang-1500.3.9.4)
➜  function git:(master) ✗ rustc -g -C opt-level=0 src/main.rs -o main
➜  function git:(master) ✗ rust-lldb main                             
(lldb) command script import "/Users/caelansar/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/etc/lldb_lookup.py"
(lldb) command source -s 0 '/Users/caelansar/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/etc/lldb_commands'
Executing commands in '/Users/caelansar/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/etc/lldb_commands'.
(lldb) type synthetic add -l lldb_lookup.synthetic_lookup -x ".*" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)String$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^&(mut )?str$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^&(mut )?\\[.+\\]$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(std::ffi::([a-z_]+::)+)OsString$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)Vec<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)VecDeque<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)BTreeSet<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)BTreeMap<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(std::collections::([a-z_]+::)+)HashMap<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(std::collections::([a-z_]+::)+)HashSet<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)Rc<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(alloc::([a-z_]+::)+)Arc<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(core::([a-z_]+::)+)Cell<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(core::([a-z_]+::)+)Ref<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(core::([a-z_]+::)+)RefMut<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(core::([a-z_]+::)+)RefCell<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(core::([a-z_]+::)+)NonZero<.+>$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^core::num::([a-z_]+::)*NonZero.+$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^(std::([a-z_]+::)+)PathBuf$" --category Rust
(lldb) type summary add -F lldb_lookup.summary_lookup  -e -x -h "^&(mut )?(std::([a-z_]+::)+)Path$" --category Rust
(lldb) type category enable Rust
(lldb) target create "main"
Current executable set to '/Users/caelansar/RustroverProjects/function/main' (arm64).
(lldb) b 18
Breakpoint 1: where = main`main::main::h8d79616f9b6b86ce + 96 at main.rs:18:13, address = 0x000000010000169c
(lldb) r
Process 96136 launched: '/Users/caelansar/RustroverProjects/function/main' (arm64)
Process 96136 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'main', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000010000169c main`main::main::h8d79616f9b6b86ce at main.rs:18:13
   15       let ptr: fn(i32, i32) -> i32 = add; // function pointer
   16       let x = item(1, 2);
   17       let y = item1(3, 2);
-> 18       let z = ptr(1, 2);
   19       assert_eq!(3, x);
   20       assert_eq!(1, y);
   21       assert_eq!(3, z);
Target 0: (main) stopped.
(lldb) v
(int (*)(int, int)) item = 0x0001000000030000
(int (*)(int, int)) item1 = 0x0000010000000300
(int (*)(int, int)) ptr = 0x00000001000015b4 (main`main::add::h243b87047811e43e at main.rs:2)
(int) x = 3
(int) y = 1
(lldb) n
Process 96136 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'main', queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x00000001000016b8 main`main::main::h8d79616f9b6b86ce at main.rs:19:5
   16       let x = item(1, 2);
   17       let y = item1(3, 2);
   18       let z = ptr(1, 2);
-> 19       assert_eq!(3, x);
   20       assert_eq!(1, y);
   21       assert_eq!(3, z);
   22   }
Target 0: (main) stopped.
(lldb) v
(int (*)(int, int)) item = 0x0001000000030000
(int (*)(int, int)) item1 = 0x0000010000000300
(int (*)(int, int)) ptr = 0x00000001000015b4 (main`main::add::h243b87047811e43e at main.rs:2)
(int) x = 3
(int) y = 1
(int) z = 3
(lldb) 

What does the address 0x0001000000030000 / 0x0000010000000300 represent? They don’t seem to be addresses of function instructions.
Not sure if it’s related to the OS, I’m using an Apple Silicon MBP.

The answer, ultimately, is that the value is irrelevant, because function items are zero-sized types.  They do not need to point anywhere since the type information alone tells the compiler which function to call.
fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

// Wrapper to allow us to "name" T using a value of T.
fn size_of<T>(_: T) -> usize {
    std::mem::size_of::<T>()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(0, size_of(add));
}

The value shown in the debugger might be arbitrary or indeterminate, but it doesn't matter because this value is never actually used.  You might as well be asking what the value of () is -- in fact, if you do let item2 = (); and then inspect that value in the debugger, I suspect you will see some other nonsense value.
Note that when I have rustc emit LLVM IR, even at optimization level zero there is nothing emitted for item nor item1.  What you're seeing is likely just a quirk of lldb.

Remember that the "Rust" type system in lldb is implemented by "pretending Rust is C++" so from lldb's perspective, these function pointers are C function pointers, and so showing their value is the reasonable thing to do.  You'd have to cook up a summary formatter - not sure how you would write the matcher - for these entities if you wanted to show the "Rust interpretation".
